# How to Zoom Google Maps Javascript API to level 25

Tags: leaflet, google-maps-api, json, zoom

Cannot Zoom Google Maps Javascript API  after 1:564 (zoomlevel: 20) in Mapstore. Can anyone help me to solve this cause my layer keeps on zooming but the map is stuck at zoom 20, I want to zoom it to 25.

here is my config.json

```
{
  "map": {
    "projection": "EPSG:900913",
    "units": "m",
    "center": {
      "x": 1250000.000000,
      "y": 5370000.000000,
      "crs": "EPSG:900913"
    },
    "zoom": 5,
    "maxExtent": [
      -20037508.34, -20037508.34,
      20037508.34, 20037508.34
    ],
    "layers": [{
      "type": "google",
      "title": "google map",
      "name": "SATELLITE",
      "source": "google",
      "group": "background",
      "visibility": false
    }]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

google haven't tile set for 25. zoom level. You can change map options but tile image will looking bad resolution

Comment: how to do that? because I want it to zoom to 25 so that my map and layer will zoom the same....